# run the same script but with a different variable each given period of time

Tags: php, cron

Let's say I have a text file that has a list of urls, from which social media comments must be parsed regularly. I don't want to parse comments from all pages at once as that's a significant load. I need to run my script with a different `$url` variable corresponding to a line from that text file each 5 minutes.

So it must take the first line as `$url` and complete the script using this variable, after 5 minutes the variable `$url` must change to the second line from that file and complete the script with it, in another 5 minutes the same must be repeated for the third line from that file, and so on. When it reaches the last line, it must start from the beginning.

Sorry, can't show any attempts, because I have no idea how to implement it, and I couldn't come up with an appropriate search request either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a 1st step you should setup cron job (ex: `cron.php`) which will be executed every 5 minutes.

[crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

```
*/5 * * * * /path_to_your_cron_php/cron.php
```

Lets assume that you have your urls in file named `file.txt` in this simple txt format.

file.txt

```
https://www.google.com/
https://www.alexa.com/
https://www.yourdomain.com/
```

Lets create file where we will keep index of url we want to execute next in `index.txt` which will have just 1 line with 1 value.

index.txt

```
0
```

cron.php

```
<?php

$fileWithUrl  = '/path/to/your/file.txt';
$index  = (int)file_get_contents('/path/to/your/index.txt');
$urls = file($fileWithUrl);
$maxIndex = count($urls);
$url = $urls[$index];
your_parse_function($url);
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/index.txt',($index >= $maxIndex) ? 0 : $index++);
```

As you can see this script reads content of `file.txt` and `index.txt`. Convert 1st one to an array of urls and cast `index.txt` to integer index. 
After execution of `your_parse_function()` this script will replace the content of `index.php` with incremented index or reset it to 0 if it is bigger than number of urls we have in `file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, looks simple. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I decided to choose it as the solution because it answer my question exactly. Even though I decided to follow a different approach (each user reports their own comments via ajax on beforeunload).

Answer (score 1):

Since variables don't persist through different runs, you'd need to keep track of the ones you have already parsed and the ones that remain outside of your code.

The most efficient way would be to have a semaphore table with each URL on a single row, paired with a parsed/pending flag.
Each time the cron runs, select a single row from the semaphore table which is flagged `pending`:

assuming it's done on mysql:

```
select url
from semaphore
where status='pending'
limit 1;
```

this will select one (whatever one) url that's yet to be parsed. Take that as input from your parser and after parsing, update the flag to `parsed` so it's not selected again.

Other approaches would be to keep a counter on a text file or a database table. Each time the cron runs, check what the counter is and process the next number. After processing, update the counter to the current value + 1.

EDIT: 
This may be a simple way to solve your re-iteration with a variable list of URLs

1.- Create a table with the following fields:
id, url, status (pending/parsed), last_updated (datetime)

2.- on each run of your cron:

```
select url from semaphore where status='pending' order by last_updated asc limit 1
```

3.- if a url is returned, process that. Upon completion, update the status to `parsed` and last_updated to the current timestamp.
if nothing is returned, update every row to status = `pending` (but not the `last_updated` field) and then re-run the above query.

By doing this, you can be sure that when starting over, you'll be first processing the url that has been "waiting" longer

Comment: OP never mentioned any DB involved.

Comment: very aware of that. That's why it's not the sole suggestion made. However, OP doesn't explicitly mention DB's are off the table, so for the sake of completeness I provided both paths :)

Comment: Perhaps it's indeed the most efficient way, but my CMS uses Doctrine, and I would have to write a new extension to add the additional column `status` to the table with page entities... I imagine this as a bigger-than-needed job. But might give it a try nevertheless.

Comment: keep it simple. @Alex's textfile-based solution would be a better solution in your case (as the effort to use a DB for support would far outweigh the benefit you are seeking)

Comment: I'm actually going to try this solution, because I would need to use Doctrine anyway to gather my urls. But one question: how is it going to restart the cycle after parsing from all pages? If all pages will be marked as parsed... As mentioned in my question, I'm not parsing comments from each page once. I regularly check for new comments/edits/deletions. That's why I need this in the first place.

Comment: I think it needs to somehow mark only the last parsed entry as parsed, then select the next entry, and upon parsing it mark it as parsed, then unmark the previous entry. But how will it know which next entry to parse? I think more complicated queries are necessary.

Comment: plot thickens :) is the number of URLs that require parsing fixed? It may be simpler than it sounds with a little bit more code (but simple queries)

Comment: No, the number of urls is not fixed either (initially, I was going to create a new list of urls on a daily basis). I think I need to add something like `AND id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM semaphore WHERE status='parsed')`. Right? I only need to find the Doctrine alternative to this xD

Comment: updated my answer with some pseudo-code that may help

Answer (score 0):

PHP is pretty stateless by default, so once a script has finished executing, everything is wiped.

What I would do: Try a for loop, and use PHP's `sleep()` function for a break in between URLs. You can either run that loop as a cron job (better), or put it in a `while (true)` loop and never let it "finish".

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: `sleep` is worst option ever

Comment: Yes, if we're going for a never ending loop. Can you explain the issue with a for loop for the URLs, sleeping a few seconds between each URL, and executing the script executed as a cron job every 5 minutes?

Comment: You can check some opinions here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz In my practice I see `sleep` as evil. We lose control and nee to implement some "monitoring" tool over this script. Because in case it crushes - we don't know, in case it stuck somewhere else we don't know. But if we implement it with cron we can check logs and have statistics what is average execution time for example, or if there is error message on some items (ex: some url becomes invalid etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with only the things you currently are using (PHP and that text file), you could just remove that first line from the text file when you process it and then append it back to the end once you're done. You'd either have to open two successive file handles or seek to the end of the file using one, but you wouldn't need any additional data structures/SQL/what have you. Make the text file itself rotate while you blindly fire cron every five minutes.